# Add condition in macro

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uialertview

How to add following condition in macro

if (![NSStringFromClass([[self superview] class]) isEqualToString:@"_UIModalItemAlertContentView"])

I want to add these two methods only if superClass of tableView category is not alertView

```
#if ([NSStringFromClass([[self superview] class]) isEqualToString:@"_UIModalItemAlertContentView"])

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([self.customDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:touchBegan:withEvent:)]) {
        [self.customDelegate tableView:self touchBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([self.customDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:touchEnded:withEvent:)]) {
        [self.customDelegate tableView:self touchEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define YourMacroName(_view_) ([NSStringFromClass([[_view_ superview] class]) isEqualToString:@"_UIModalItemAlertContentView"])

if(YourMacroName){
   //do something
}
```

Is this what you want?